# Jenkinsfile, prebuild script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm a using the jenkins pipeline. My usecase is that the developer are using a simple *.ini file that is parsed by a python script to add or remove stage within the jenkinsfile whenever they want. I don't want them to manually edit the jenkinsfile because they won't know how it works.

Expected behaviour is:
When a build is triggered I would like to first execute a python script which might write into the jenkinsfile to add/remove stage according to the *.ini file.

As far as I understand, when an event trigger a jenkins build, the first thing it does is opening the jenkinsfile. However I would like to know if it's possible to run some prebuild script before that ?

Thanks

Edit: here's a simple view of run of the pipeline (blue ocean UI)
[image: Pipeline]

The ini file might for example remove in the stage Compilation the step Building Plan C by removing the groovy code doing that in the jenkins file

Comment: what about changing the model to [Parametrized pipelines](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines) ? I have not used it myself but seems a better fit for your case. So instead of having a file to be parsed in order to decide what to do, you can make this based on a passed parameter and that's it, what do you think ?

Comment: I'm going to look into it this afternoon to see if it fits my needs, thanks for your answer

Comment: Okay, I will also try to prepare a simple example and post it as a full answer later

Comment: Thanks, I managed to  add parameter within my pipeline thanks to your link and the following [JenkinsMinute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_tvlaIeQUQ). However I didn't manage to use the API call to start a build with custom parameter without user interaction. I'm currently checking if this behaviour will be fine for every usecase i though of and I'll come back to you later.

Comment: When the build is started automatically, default parameter will be use which won't work for me. For example when pushing to a branch default parameter will be used, but I might be able to use the git hook to start a script which will parse the *.ini file and then generate the correct url with the parameter required to start Jenkins.

Comment: If the parameters does not fit, you can use a json file and parse it with jq instead of ini files and python. I will try to prepare an example as soon as possible but i am just writing what you can do in here until i can write an example

Comment: You can use Scripted Pipeline to parse the `.ini` file , then use `if` to determine the stage to run or not dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an example for reference.

```groovy
    node {
    
    
      git url: '', branch: '', credentialsId: ''
    
    
      def parseStr = sh(script: 'python parser.py xxx.ini', returnStdout: true).trim()

      // the python parser expect to return a JSON string like: 
      // {'run_stage1': false, 'run_stage2': true}
    
      def parseObj = readJSON text: parseStr
    
      
    
        stage('stage 1') {
           if(parseObj.run_stage1) {
             echo 'stage1'
             ...
           }    
        }
       
        stage('stage 1') {
            if(parseObj.run_stage2) {
               echo 'stage1'
               ....
            }    
        }
    
    }
```

Jenkins pipeline had supply [apis](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/): `readJSON, readYaml, readProperties` to read JSON, YAML and Properties files.

If you choose any of them to replace `ini` file, you can drop the python parser to make your pipeline more simple

Comment: The python script is not needed, I only need to provide specific parameter to the pipeline, it looks like those APIs might do the job too.
Thanks, I'm looking into it